# Building SELECT tag from XML in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, dom, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a `select` tag with `option`s from an array. I create the array from XML as follows:

```
 foreach( $xml->children() as $key => $value ) {
                $nodes = array();
                 foreach( $value->children() as $k => $v ) {
                             $nodes[ ( string ) $v->getName() ] = ( string ) $v;
                      }
                $node = ( string ) $value->getName();
                $xml2Array[ $node ][] = $nodes;
            }
        $data['item']  = $xml2Array;
```

And then I get this array:

```
Array
(
    [Item] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ItemCode] => 0002684
                    [MainUOMCode] => PAIR
                    [ItemName] => SHOES (8623; PINK)
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ItemCode] => 0003062
                    [MainUOMCode] => PAIR
                    [ItemName] => SHOES (8625; PINK)
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ItemCode] => 0003116
                    [MainUOMCode] => PAIR
                    [ItemName] => SHOES (8624; RED)
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ItemCode] => 0003125
                    [MainUOMCode] => PAIR
                    [ItemName] => SHOES (8624; YELLOW)
                )
```

I want to fill the `select` `option`s with the array items:

```
<select class="form-control js-example-diacritics">
                                        <option></option>
                                        <?php foreach ($item as $key => $arr){ ?>    
                                        <option value="<?=$arr['ItemCode'];?>"><?=$arr['ItemName'];?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
```

But the code above fails:

```
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: ItemCode</p>
<p>Filename: mutasi_antarserver/add_dagang.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 161</p>
```

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data['item']  = $xml2Array;

echo '<select class="form-control js-example-diacritics">';

foreach($data['item'] as $item)
{
   echo '<option value="'.$item['ItemCode'].'">'.$item['ItemName'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

i think if your are using Codeigniter then try

```
<select class="form-control js-example-diacritics">
<option></option>
<?php foreach ($item['Item'] as $key => $arr){ ?>    
<option value="<?=$arr['ItemCode'];?>"><?=$arr['ItemName'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using the SimpleXML extension (it is evident from the way you use [`children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method).

### Iterating `SimpleXMLElement`

Since [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) implements `Traversable` interface, you can simply iterate the object in order to fetch the children. Also, it is possible to access the children of `SimpleXMLElement` as object properties, i.e. with the `->` operator.

**Example**

```
<?php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<root>
  <Item>
    <ItemCode>00002345</ItemCode>
    <MainUOMCode>PAIR</MainUOMCode>
    <ItemName>SHOES (...)</ItemName>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemCode>032434</ItemCode>
    <MainUOMCode>XPAIR</MainUOMCode>
    <ItemName>SHOESxxx (...)</ItemName>
  </Item>
</root>
XML;

echo '<select class="form-control js-example-diacritics">', PHP_EOL;
$items = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo '<option value="', $item->ItemCode, '">',
        $item->ItemName, '</option>', PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</select>';
```

*Output*

```
<select class="form-control js-example-diacritics">
<option value="00002345">SHOES (...)</option>
<option value="032434">SHOESxxx (...)</option>
</select>
```

### Using the Array Syntax

But if you insist on using the `children()` method and the array syntax, you can cast the `SimpleXMLElement` to array:

```
foreach ($items->children() as $item) {
    $item = (array) $item;
    echo '<option value="', $item['ItemCode'], '">',
        $item['ItemName'], '</option>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

By the way, your code fails, because you are trying to access object as an array, and the object (`SimpleXMLElement`) doesn't implement `ArrayAccess`, or `ArrayObject`.

---

Note, you should escape the HTML content with `htmlspecialchars()` function.